# How to cancel paypal transactions and refund the amount from PayPal in ANDROID?

Tags: android, paypal

There are many examples explaining payment using PayPal but I need how to cancel PayPal transactions and refund the amount from PayPal in Android?
Any one help me out.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible on Android's side to cancel your transaction once its done.
You need to do on the server side after passing your Client ID and Payment ID